# Preserve connection object for login

Tags: java, spring, rest, session, serialization

This is sort of architectural question, however, in my project I've developed API interface that holds 3d party library used to connect to 3d party API. My own API interface is used by another service (consumer).

**Schematic diagram**
[image: Schematic diagram]

The problem is that connection to 3d party API is held by a Login object (that is obviously implemented in 3d party library), and every request is made through or by passing this Login object.

The question is how to preserver/save this object in order not to create every time new Login. It does implement Serialization but it contains non serializable classes inside, so I would have to write a huge wrapper for that.

I also thought of sessions, but they should be unique for every new Login option (by the way, there are many users that are using Login, not one), and I have no clue how to manage multiple unique sessions for every unique Login and then how to call this specific session.

If it helps, I'm writing project using Spring Boot.

**Update**
I've researched more session solution (specifically multiple session using Servlets and aliases stored into the cookie) - it won't suite me, as application designed to hold hundreds of connections while cookie is limited in size.

Comment: Well, and a question itself: how to preserver this Login object without need to re-Login every time new operation is requested from the consumer?

Comment: Sessions are made for cases like this.

Comment: Well, that is my option, but after implementation of session I couldn't separate Login objects. Generally, I made Login object, executed some operations, switched to another client and then back to the first (without new login) - as a result, new operations where executed through last created Login connection. Meaning that everything was made in one session (after research the problem was in my API consumer, that actually was single client, so session was only for him).

Answer (score 0):

I've returned to idea with serialization. As a result, I managed to serialize part of Login Object responsible for connection, and then to re-use it.

If somebody cares, I've used [kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) for serialization